# Best way to determine what order was given to my application?

Tags: c, windows

I want to write a caculator that waits for the user to give it orders.
for example:
add 1 2
sub 12 4
What is the best way to find out what order the user gave and the token(s) given after that order?
I'm writing my project in C on Windows and it's  Console-Based.

Comment: Are you trying to make an interactive desk calculator such as `bc` or `dc`? Or do you want to make a command that will perform one calculation and then quit?

Comment: @sarnold It take an order and print the result! very simple one!  I want to know is there any libraray or something I can use for taking an order?

Comment: Well, it's a matter of simple parsing of `argv` contents or writing a neat parser using flex and bison -- the simple `argv` parsing will work if you want to call a command line tool over and over again; the more complicated flex and bison approach gives you a far more powerful tool.

Comment: @sarnold I want to run my application once. I guess it's not related to commad line parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `scanf`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char cmd[1024];
    int a, b;

    printf ("Enter input: ");
    scanf ("%s %d %d",cmd, &a, &b);  
    if(strcmp(cmd,"add")==0) {
        printf ("Result: %d\n", a + b);
    } else if(strcmp(cmd,"sub")==0) {
        printf ("Result: %d", a - b);
    } else {
        printf ("Unrecognized command: '%s'\n", cmd);
    }
}
```

You should look at [lex and yacc](http://epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/) if you plan to build a complex one.

Answer (score 2):

Read lines from standard input. `fgets` can be useful.
Parse each line. `strtok_r` can help here (I always prefer it over `strtok`, which causes nasty bugs when things get complicated).
Compare the first token with a each command in the list of known commands.
Do what needs to be done.